# Why doesn't this c give an output?

Tags: c

Here it is, the code that confuses me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
    unsigned long int *a = (unsigned long int *)0xA000000;
  
    *a = 20;
  
    printf("%p\n", &a);
  
    return 0;
}
```

The code ran and gave no error but did give an exit status of `-1`, which I don't understand.

I also couldn't understand why this C code had no result. After searching for what exit status -1 meant I came back with nothing. My intention with the code was to write to 0xA0000. However, it didn't change any pixels and didn't print an output. I also tried taking away the longs but that didn't work either. (They were there because far wasn't working so I tried typing long instead. I figured since far pointers are also called long pointers. I am very new to c and can't tell if that did anything.)

Comment: What is stored on the location `0xA000000` on your system? Are you sure you really can use that location? What is your assignment? What are you really supposed to do? Who told you to do that? Are you reading some old DOS documentation where you could access all addresses in the memory map (assuming a correct segment selector)? On a modern protected system memory isn't "absolute" like it used to be, you can't directly access random addresses in the virtual memory of your process.

Comment: On a totally different note: Are you really supposed to print a pointer to the `a` variable? It prints the location of the variable `a` itself, not what it points to, nor the value stored at the location that `a` points to. The expression `&a` will give you a value of type `unsigned long **`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The mention of far pointers certainly does strongly suggest dos.

Comment: *The code ran and gave no error but did give an exit status of -1* Then it **did** give an error; if it didn't the status would be 0. Probably raised a signal from illegal memory access.

Comment: I thought that the memory bit was the first pixel on the top left and I'm trying to figure out currently what needs to happen to change its color. I am not sure I can use the location without far pointers & It is an experiment to figure out how c can use memory. (In other words, I told myself / no one told me to.) I would also like to state the print function was to test if a was a different memory address or at 0xA0000.

Comment: This is not portable C code.  For one thing, what is at address `0xA000000`?  You also mention a different address, `0xA0000`, in the description.  They can't both be right.  And why are you trying to print the address of `a`?  It's just a local variable, so its address shouldn't be of particular interest.

Comment: I still meant 0xA000000 but tried making it shorter for the sake of saving time as all that came after were more zeros. Also thanks to you all for trying to help so far. Another thing is that again the print function is to figure out how far the pointer reference will go through to retrieve the data (Though I probably don't need to thinking back on it).

Comment: Whatever resource (book, tutorial, or other) that you have been using to learn about graphics seems to be at least 20 or more years old. Direct access to the graphics memory of a PC-like system haven't been possible since about then, when DOS was retired. The only way to do that these days is through an emulator, and require a compiler that can generate code for such an ancient environment.

Comment: Oh. I tried basing the code off something from dos thinking it was still possible. Even since posting, I tried adding ```stdio.h``` after learning it's the source code for near, far, and huge pointers. This discovery is rather sad but at least I still have libraries to do something similar with screen drwing.

Comment: Either that or I could just learn assembly, which is on all systems as far as I'm aware and directly deals with memory. If that previous statement doesn't apply to all languages.

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you're using, you just can't go around poking at memory on a protected OS like Windows is these days (and Linux always has been, as well as macOS). That's just not how it works. If you tell us what you *really* want to do, then perhaps we can help you with that instead of you getting stuck on doing the DOS way which just won't work.

Comment: "tried adding `stdio.h` after learning it's the source code for near, far, and huge pointers". Those are relics of Turbo C from 30 to 40 years ago. The `stdio.h` is needed because you use `printf()`. The video memory is not directly accessible by a user program any more, unless perhaps you are using a DOSBOX simulation.

Comment: A graphics library like OpenGL will let you read and write pixels and will hide all the complexity of modern GPUs.

Comment: Just to make it clear, `far` and `long` are not even remotely the same. `far` pointers were used with 16-bit segmented memory addresses, which went out of fashion about 1995. You want to learn about 64-bit programs, not about 16-bit ones. (And yes, I know that some Windows pointer types still have an `L` in them, but that means nothing anymore. It is just a remnant from Windows 3).

Answer (score 1):

The code has undefined behavior: attempting to write to memory at address `0xA000000` may work on some systems, notably on MS/DOS with an address of `0xA0000000`, but may cause a segmentation fault on your target system.

The segmentation fault causes the program to terminate before `printf()` has a chance to output anything and with a non exit status, eg -1.

If you run the program from a terminal window, the segmentation fault might be reported by the shell, but it is possible that it occurs silently in your IDE.

If your intend is to write pixels to the graphics screen of a PC, be aware that this method does not work anymore with modern operating systems where the system memory is protected and each process had a virtual memory space that is separate from the motherboard physical layout.